# UI is not working after adding OAuthService in AppComponent constructor

Tags: angular, openid-connect

`Angular`

After adding  OIDC OAuthService the UI is not hot showing anything. Below is angular code
.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { OAuthService } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'AngProject';
  constructor(private auth:OAuthService){

  }
}
```

[image]

`Error`

```
core.js:6486 ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[OAuthService -> HttpClient -> HttpClient -> HttpClient]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
    at NullInjector.get (core.js:11108)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:11275)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:11275)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:11275)
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.js:4758)
    at Module.ɵɵinject (core.js:4762)
    at Object.OAuthService_Factory [as factory] (angular-oauth2-oidc.js:3050)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.js:11445)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:11264)
    at NgModuleRef$1.get (core.js:25340)
```

Comment: The console may contain more information. Maybe you did not provide the service in your NgModule? (if it's from a library, you might need to add the library module to the imports array of the module)

Comment: I have already added the oAuth service in AppModule

Comment: Can you add console output to your question? usually, when the app is not loading, you get some red text on the console, that should help resolving the issue.

Comment: Also, adding the service may not be enough, maybe check https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc#importing-the-ngmodule if you followed the steps correctly.

Answer (score 0):

`In App Module ts I added below dependencies`

```
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http'
import { OAuthModule } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';
import {UrlHelperService} from "angular-oauth2-oidc";
```

`And I declared the service and module in Ng Module like below`

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    OAuthModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [OAuthService,UrlHelperService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```